# How can I add new files to an existing github-repository from a different path than before

Tags: git, github, repository, push

I changed my file tree and now want to push the changes I made to a file that I have in a remote repository. I changed the path but want to push the existing but updated file to my existing GitHub repository that I used before. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply:

- clone your GitHub repository in a new  separate local folder
- copy over the files that you have changed in that new local rpeository
- add, commit and push